# how to check if char conforms to charset?

Tags: rebol, red

tl;dr can't get parse to work with single letter

I'm currently learning Red, so I may be missing basic things, but in general I want to check if a password contains uppercase characters; this was my first attempt (I know it's logically invalid):

```
num-uppercase: (length? (difference/case password (lowercase password))) / 2
```

The idea was to convert to a lowercase string and then compare each, but `difference` seems to convert a string to a set(?).

Now I moved on from that to looping over each letter like so:

```
is-uppercase: false
foreach letter password [
    if letter <> lowercase letter [
        is-uppercase: true
        break
    ]
]
```

But then I wanted to check if a single `char!` `letter` is a special character:

```
foreach letter password [
    if parse letter special [
        is-special: true
    ]
]
```

But I get an error:

```
*** Script Error: parse does not allow char! for its input argument
*** Where: parse
*** Stack:
```

I've been looking for something to be able to check if a char conforms to a charset, but wasn't able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse works with almost any kind of series: that is, with a collection of items put in a succession. `string!` is such a series, but `char!` is not.

```
>> series? #"."
== false
>> scalar? #"."
== true
```

To check if your password contains uppercase characters, you first need to create a `bitset!` that represents such characters:

```
>> upper: charset [#"A" - #"Z"]
== make bitset! #{00000000000000007FFFFFE0}
```

After that, you can use it to construct a Parse *rule* and check the conformity of input; for example, is password all uppercased? Some inputs will match, some will not.

```
>> parse "YES" [some upper]
== true
>> parse "no" [some upper]
== false
```

Is it written in sentence-case? Different grammars you'll come up with can yield the same result.

```
>> parse "Sentence" [upper to end]
== true
>> parse "Sentence" [upper any [not upper skip]]
== true
```

Finally, if you want to check if there's at least one uppercase letter, something like this should do:

```
>> parse "aBc" [to upper to end]
== true
>> parse "abc" [to upper to end]
== false
```

If you are looking for password with only one single uppercased letter and no more, then:

```
>> parse "aBc" [thru upper any [not upper skip]]
== true
>> parse "aBC" [thru upper any [not upper skip]]
== false
```

To answer the original question directly: if you have a `charset!` and a `char!`, then you can check if the latter belongs to the former with:

```
>> pick upper #"a"
== false
>> pick upper #"A"
== true
>> pick upper [#"A" #"b"]
== false
>> pick upper [#"A" #"B"]
== true
>> pick upper "Ab"
== false
>> pick upper "AB"
== true
```

---

I strongly recommend getting your bearings with Red prior to tackling Parse (which FYI has an official [documentation](https://github.com/red/red/wiki/%5BLINKS%5D-Learning-resources)). The best way to do that is by joining [Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/red/help) to get promptly help with your questions and code, and by studying community-provided [learning resources](https://github.com/red/red/wiki/%5BLINKS%5D-Learning-resources); [Rebol/Core User Guide](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore.html) is a good starting point.

Comment: `pick` is very nice, although for checking whether somehting is uppercase I still would prefer to use the `uppercase` function in case the string has diacritics and other non-standard characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution in Red would be to convert `char!` to `integer!` and use [path notation](https://github.com/red/docs/blob/master/en/datatypes/bitset.adoc#5-path-notation):

```
>> special: charset ".:?"
== make bitset! #{0000000000020021}
>> special/(to integer! #"a")
== false
>> special/(to integer! #".")
== true
```

Comment: That doesn't look very idiomatic. `pick special character` does the same and does not require any conversions.

Comment: Moreso, conversion to `integer!` is not required in such case, try e.g. `special/(#".")`.

Answer (score 0):

I can use `to-string` to convert the char to a string. It's one way to do it.

```
parse to-string #"." [special]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without parse, but according to what you want to get with your first attempt

```
>> strict-equal? lowercase copy pass: "ABcc"  pass
== false
>> strict-equal? lowercase copy pass: "abcc"  pass
== true
```

You need *copy* because it alters the original, *strict-equal?* because plain *equal?* does not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase.

*difference* shows the diiferent items of two sets. see *help difference*.
A solution with difference you can get with

```
>> same: empty? difference/case pass: "ABcc" lowercase copy pass
== false
>> same:  empty? difference/case pass: "aabc" lowercase copy pass
== true
```

Answer (score 0):

For individual characters, `find` can also be used with a charset.

```
>> upper: charset [#"A" - #"Z"]
== make bitset! #{00000000000000007FFFFFE0}
>> find upper #"x"
== none
>> find upper #"X"
== true
```